# Databricks with Google Ads API Authentication

Tags: yaml, google-oauth, databricks, google-ads-api, google-ad-manager

I was wondering if anyone has had experience authenticating for Google Ads API via Databricks. The Google Ad Manager documentation indicates that a YAML file should be created using the service account credentials, but it's not an option for me to upload that to DBFS based on some references I've read about since they are credentials.

Wondering if there are any suggestions on how to authenticate on Databricks using YAML or another format.

Here is the link to the GAM documentation on authentication: https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/api/start